# Display the the total amount of the same vowel

Tags: c#

I am trying to display the total number of the same vowels when I input a word. For example : cheesecake. 
Total vowels are 5 (e,e,e,a,e) and the total number of the same vowels (which is 'e') is 4.
The code I did,is still showing the number of the same vowels to 5.
Is there something wrong on my code?

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a word or phrase : ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        char[] listOfVowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };

        int vowel = 0;
        int sameVowel = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (listOfVowels.Contains(input[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input[i]);
                vowel++;

                if(input[i] == input[i])
                {
                    sameVowel++;
                }

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"The total number of vowel are : {vowel}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The total of the same number of vowel are : {sameVowel}");
    }
```

The total number of vowel are : 5
The total of the same number of vowel are : 5

Comment: if(input[i] == input[i]) looks incorrect and is always true

Comment: Mind me, what do you mean by "same vowels"? If a word had 3 'e's and 3 'a's what do you expect it to do? How do you decide which is the 'same vowel'?

Comment: @Everyone That is an exceptionally well made point!

Comment: I posted an answer which should be efficient and should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Enter a word or phrase : ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine()/*"cheesecake"*/;

    char[] listOfVowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };

    int vowel = 0;

    vowel = input.Count(z => listOfVowels.Contains(z));

    var sameVowelPair = input.Where(c => listOfVowels.Contains(c)).GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(s1 => s1.Key, s1=> s1.Count()).OrderByDescending(w => w.Value).FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine($"The total number of vowel are : {vowel}");
    Console.WriteLine($"The total of the same number of vowel are : {sameVowelPair.Value}");
}
```

**Outputs:**

- The total number of vowel are : 5
- The total of the same number of vowel are : 4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, create a list to store vowel, and use linq to count same vowel

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a word or phrase : ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            char[] listOfVowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };

            int vowel = 0;
            int sameVowel = 0;
            List<char> vowers = new List<char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (listOfVowels.Contains(input[i]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(input[i]);
                    vowel++;

                    vowers.Add(input[i]);

                    //if(vowers.Contains(input[i]))
                    //{
                    //    sameVowel++;
                    //}

                }
            }

            sameVowel = vowers.GroupBy(_ => _).Where(_ => _.Count() > 1).Sum(_ => _.Count());
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The total number of vowel are : {0}", vowel));
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The total of the same number of vowel are : {0}", sameVowel));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the pillars of OOP and the Single Responsibility Principle, you could encapsulate this logic into a class that will handle this logic for you

**Class**

```
public class VowelStatistics
{
    private readonly string word;

    public VowelStatistics(string word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public IEnumerable<char> Vowels => word.Where(c => "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c));

    public int VowelCount => Vowels.Count();

    public char MostFrequentVowel => Vowels
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .First();

    public int MostFrequentVowelCount => Vowels
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .Max(g => g.Count());

    // Adding this as per @Everyone's comment, which will give you vowel groupings by frequency.
    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, char>> VowelsByFrequency => Vowels
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
}
```

**Usage**

```
VowelStatistics vs = new VowelStatistics("cheesecake");
```

**Results**

> vs.Vowels = { 'e', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'e' }
>
> vs.VowelCount = 5
>
> vs.MostFrequentVowel = 'e'
>
> vs.MostFrequentVowelCount = 4

Comment: What is the space/size complexity analysis of this, given there is a lot of linq involved? I do like the assumption of 'samevowel' being the most frequent one. That makes sense.

Comment: @Everyone I'm not entirely sure. I'd have to refer to some LINQ documentation to work that out. No doubt there are some optimizations to be made.

Comment: @Everyone some amortization wouldn't go amiss either.

Comment: I have posted a different answer using .NET 4.7 or later versions.

Comment: @Everyone - It's `O(5N)` or `(O10N)` depending on the use of case. It's linear on `N`.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this (no LINQ involved):

```
static (int, char, int) vowelStats(string str)
{
  // VOWEL ONLY DICTIONARY
  Dictionary<char, int> counts = new Dictionary<char, int>()
  {
    {'a', 0} , { 'e', 0} , { 'i', 0} , { 'o', 0} , { 'u', 0} 
  };

  int vowels = 0;
  char high = '\0';

  foreach(char c in str)
  {
    char c1 = Char.ToLower(c); // convert letter to lowercase first
    // if dictionary has the character, then it must be a vowel
    if (counts.ContainsKey(c1))
    {
      counts[c1]++;  // vowel itself count
      vowels++;      // total vowel count
      if (!counts.ContainsKey(high)) high = c1; // will only be true once
      if(vowels - counts[c1] < vowels - counts[high]) // update current most frequent
        high = c1;
    }
  }

  if(!counts.ContainsKey(high)) // if no vowels found, high will be '\0'
    return (0, '\0', 0);
  return (vowels, high, counts[high]);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.Write("Enter a word or phrase : ");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();

  int vowels, mostFrequentVowelCount;
  char mostFrequenctVowel;

  (vowels, mostFrequenctVowel, mostFrequentVowelCount) = vowelStats(input);
  Console.WriteLine("Total number of vowels: {0}", vowels);
  Console.WriteLine("Most frequent vowel: {0}", mostFrequenctVowel);
  Console.WriteLine("Most frequent vowel count: {0}", mostFrequentVowelCount);
}
```

Output:

> Enter a word or phrase : cheesecake
>
> Total number of vowels: 5
>
> Most frequent vowel: e
>
> Most frequent vowel count: 4

Notes:

1) I assumed what you meant by "same vowel" is "the most frequent vowel".

2) The code will only work (as is) in .Net Framework 4.7 or higher (tuple functions) OR .Net Core 2 or higher.

3) Time complexity: O(N) where N is the number of characters in the string.

4) Space complexity: O(C) where C is a constant representing the number of vowels and their corresponding integers in the Dictionary, plus the few other variables.

5) In case of two vowels having been the most frequent, this function will pick the one that was encountered first. That is, in case of "woohee" it will be 'o', and in case of "weehoo" it will be 'e'.

6) I updated the code so it does not care about uppercase/lowercase. If it encounters a vowel regardless of its case, it will update one and only one counter.

7) This does not use any LINQ and should be simple enough for basic C#. The reason I used no LINQ is because of its added complexity and overhead to performance.

Comment: "no LINQ is because of its added complexity" - huh? You're saying LINQ is more complex?

Comment: Also performance is a bit of a stretch too. I ran some tests against your no-LINQ code and my heavy-LINQ code and LINQ was 5.8% slower. A single call of your code took `0.023` and my LINQ version `0.024` milliseconds. This was computing the result on a string that was `366` characters long for 1 million times each approach. That's a single **nano second** longer for LINQ.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't know what magical test you're running, I ran your code against mine for 1 million times each on the word "cheesecake" and mine finished all 1 mil in 1.393 seconds while yours took 6,852 seconds. That's about 5 times slower. Please make sure of two things: 1) your loop is actually running the million iterations (optimizations omit this). 2) You're running the queries used in your writes.

Comment: I've added my test code to my answer for you to play with.

Answer (score -1):

This is nice and simple for me:

```
string input = "cheesecake";

var query =
    from v in "aeiouAEIOU"
    join c in input on v equals c
    group c by c into gcs
    orderby gcs.Count() descending
    select gcs;

Console.WriteLine($"Vowels: {String.Join(", ", query.SelectMany(c => c))}");
Console.WriteLine($"Most Frequent Vowel: {query.First().Key}");
Console.WriteLine($"Most Frequent Vowel Count: {query.First().Count()}");
```

That gives:

```
Vowels: e, e, e, e, a
Most Frequent Vowel: e
Most Frequent Vowel Count: 4
```

---

Performance testing code:

```
static (int, char, int) vowelStatsPlain(string str)
{
    // VOWEL ONLY DICTIONARY
    Dictionary<char, int> counts = new Dictionary<char, int>()
    {
        {'a', 0} , { 'e', 0} , { 'i', 0} , { 'o', 0} , { 'u', 0}
    };

    int vowels = 0;
    char high = '\0';

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        char c1 = Char.ToLower(c); // convert letter to lowercase first
                                   // if dictionary has the character, then it must be a vowel
        if (counts.ContainsKey(c1))
        {
            counts[c1]++;  // vowel itself count
            vowels++;      // total vowel count
            if (!counts.ContainsKey(high)) high = c1; // will only be true once
            if (vowels - counts[c1] < vowels - counts[high]) // update current most frequent
                high = c1;
        }
    }

    if (!counts.ContainsKey(high)) // if no vowels found, high will be '\0'
        return (0, '\0', 0);
    return (vowels, high, counts[high]);
}

static (int, char, int) vowelStatsLinq(string str)
{
    var query =
    (
        from v in "aeiouAEIOU"
        join c in str on v equals c
        group c by c into gcs
        orderby gcs.Count() descending
        select gcs
    ).ToArray();

    var first = query.First();

    return (query.SelectMany(c => c).Count(), first.Key, first.Count());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "The information contained in this email is confidential and for the addressee only; If you are not the intended recipient of this email, please reply and let us know that an incorrect address may have been used. If you do not wish to be communicated with by email, please respond so that we may remove your address from our records. Your co-operation is appreciated.";

    Func<TimeSpan> callPlain = () =>
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        (int vowels, char mostFrequenctVowel, int mostFrequentVowelCount) = vowelStatsPlain(input);
        sw.Stop();
        return sw.Elapsed;
    };

    Func<TimeSpan> callLinq = () =>
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        (int vowels, char mostFrequenctVowel, int mostFrequentVowelCount) = vowelStatsLinq(input);
        sw.Stop();
        return sw.Elapsed;
    };

    var trials = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(x => new { plain = callPlain(), linq = callLinq() }).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine(trials.Skip(2).Average(x => x.plain.TotalMilliseconds));
    Console.WriteLine(trials.Skip(2).Average(x => x.linq.TotalMilliseconds));
    Console.WriteLine(trials.Skip(2).Average(x => x.linq.TotalMilliseconds) / trials.Skip(2).Average(x => x.plain.TotalMilliseconds));
}
```